# Need some help on logic (Xpages : Javascript) To get update Candidate No by Add on 1 if found item

Tags: javascript, xpages

View itself is sorted by decending order!(First column is "New_Exam_No")

currentExamNo = doc.getItemValueString("New_Exam_No");

var Candvw:NotesView = database.getView("(Exam Application Subject Sort by ExamNo)");

```
            var CandEntry:NotesViewEntry=Candvw.getEntryByKey(doc.getItemValueString("New_Exam_No"),true);
            if (CandEntry!=null)    //If have exam no, use this condition
                {
            var CandDoc =  CandEntry.getDocument()



                    if (Canddoc.hasItem("Candidate_No")==true)      // assign Candidate No yet?Yes! 
                    {
                        var CandNo = Canddoc.getItemValueString("Candidate_No");



                        LCandNo = "LSBS"
                        MidCandNo = @Left(CandNo,7)
                        MCandNo = @TextToNumber(@Right(MidCandNo,2)) + 1;
                        CNo = @Right("00"+@Text(MCandNo),2);
                        RExamNo = currentExamNo;
                        CandidateNo = LCandNo + "/" + CNo + "/" +RExamNo ;

                    }

                    else
                    {
                        CandidateNo = "LSBS/01/" + currentExamNo;
                    }



                }

            else    
                {
                    CandidateNo = "LSBS/01/" + currentExamNo;

                }
```

Why i always get the LSBS/01/examno as it doesn't add on 1.

Comment: I would add a few print statements in between each of these lines to output the values: `LCandNo = "LSBS"
                        MidCandNo = @Left(CandNo,7)
                        MCandNo = @TextToNumber(@Right(MidCandNo,2)) + 1;
                        CNo = @Right("00"+@Text(MCandNo),2);
                        RExamNo = currentExamNo;
                        CandidateNo = LCandNo + "/" + CNo + "/" +RExamNo ;`

Answer (score 0):

`getEntryByKey()` takes a Vector rather than a String. Try:

```
var key:java.util.Vector = new java.util.Vector();
key.add(doc.getItemValueString("New_Exam_No"));
var CandEntry:NotesViewEntry=Candvw.getEntryByKey(key,true);
```

It's been a while since I used SSJS, but I think that should work.